# Retrieve SQL query string from BigQuery query for jobId from two months ago

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

I'm trying to get the SQL query string for a custom query executed in BigQuery on a specific day from nearly two months ago.

I've executed the following command to retrieve a list of all unique values of `jobId` from that day:

```
bq ls --jobs --all --min_creation_time 1590624000000 --max_creation_time 1590710400000
```

Any idea how I can retrieve SQL query string for a specific `jobId`?

Comment: Does the answer really work?? If so, that mean you have already configured a longer default log retention!

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere According to Google Cloud documentation, the default retention is 6 months. As the date I needed to query (28th May) is less than 6 months ago, there was no special configuration required.

Comment: Can you share this piece of documentation? I only found [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods)

Comment: Under section heading "Listing jobs in a project", it states: "Your project maintains your job history for all jobs created in the past six months."

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs

Comment: Very valuable info. Thanks!!

Comment: No problems. If you found my comment above useful, please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the specific `JOB_ID`, then this command should retrieve the SQL query:

```
$ bq show -j --format=prettyjson JOB_ID | grep "query"
```